# best / correct way to add a link to button

Tags: html, button

I've been thinking about this for a little while and maybe i started the button wrong in the beginning but need to know what is the correct / best way to proceed.

I have the following code

```
<button class="more-button">FIND OUT MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

I thought I'd be able to hadd a a href after the class, but that didn't work.

At the moment I'm doing this

```
<a href="https://link.com"><button class="more-button">FIND OUT MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a>
```

Is this ok ?

Should I be doing something different ? 
thanks.

Comment: AFAIC it's pretty ok

Comment: Take care with `<button>` if you don't put a `type` it gonna be `type="submit"` instead `type="button"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using JavaScript the only thing that is the way, wich is most recommended.
You have to use a `form` tag and an `action` attribute like:

```
<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Examplevalue" />
</form>
```

You could also style a link as a button with css.

```
<a href="http://test.com" class="button">Testbutton</a>
```

CSS:

```
button{
   appearance: button;
   moz-appearance: button;
   webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with your CSS option. Makes it easier.

Comment: No problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="GET" action="YOUR_Url"><button type="submit">Text</button></form>
```

This should work if you replace YOUR_URL with the targeted URL.